# In Gmail auto remove label when email is opened

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I would like to create a "unread email" label to filter what has been unread vs read.  I am successful in creating the filter; however the unread label sticks with the message indefinitely.  Is there anyway to remove the "unread email" label once the email has been opened?  This way, only unread email gets attention then automatically disappears once its been read.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to use the multiple inboxes option.

1. go into settings/inbox.
2. change inbox type to multiple inboxes
3. define one of the 5 sections as "is:unread". (don't include the quotes)
4. Click Save Changes

You can decide where to place the multiple inbox sections, and you can decide how many to show.

That section of your inbox will show all your unread messages/conversations.

When you read an message/conversation there is a lag before it refreshes the list.